# Change callback function name

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback, xmlhttprequest

Hi so i have these two functions which `get()` is a custom ajax request function and you can see that it has two parameters url works fine but the func one which is the callback doesn't seem to change func(serverResponse); to what `document.write(serverResponse);`. So I was wondering what on earth am I doing wrong? It would be great if one of the kind developers on StackOverflow could help me out really soon. Thank you so much :)

```
function get(url, func) {
            var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhReq.open("GET", url, false);
            xhReq.send(null);
            var serverResponse = xhReq.responseText;
            func(serverResponse); // Shows "15"
        }

        get('ip.php', 'document.write');
```

Comment: Synchronous ajax is an abomination

Comment: A. Why are you using `document.write`? B. You're passing a string, not a function. C. You probably need to use `document.write.bind(document)`.

Comment: well i kinda need it because i am not going to use a 3rd-party api to get user ip address. Because I would like to use my own. Since I have already got it all working i just need this part working

Comment: With what you're doing, you might as well have the server output the IP directly, no need for ajax at all.

Comment: @nnnnnn what do you mean i am not passing a function and what difference do document.write.bind(document) do?

Comment: this project is primarily javascript based this is the only thing i am using php for and i am not going to change it all to php

Comment: sorry if i am really stubborn

Comment: @4castle Actually, I believe he correctly understood adeneo's suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
get('ip.php', 'document.write');
```

should be:

```
get('ip.php', document.write.bind(document));
```

The former passes a string; the latter passes a function.

Perhaps a more typical way to do this sort of thing:

```
get('ip.php', function (text) {
    document.write(text);
});
```

Comment: It'll need to be `document.write.bind(document)`.

Comment: Thanks! That worked I will accept your answer once the 8 minutes is up :)